# How to programatically pass a value to an R prompt (creating keyring)

Tags: r, bash

I wanted to be able to execute this code as part of an initial configuration for using R on a Ubuntu

```
library(keyring)
keyring_create("system")
```

But I am then prompted for a password. Entering it manually is of course of no problem, but I wanted to do it programmatically.. and was trying something like

```
echo "mypasswd" | Rscript -e "library(keyring); keyring_create("system")"
```

But no luck,

Doesn't have to be bash, it can be an R only solution.. does anyone can give me a tip?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That doesn't completely make sense.  You only want to create a keyring once, so why do you need a script to enter the password?  Just create it interactively, then use `keyring_unlock()` with the password as an argument to enter the password and use it.

Comment: i don't know R but the general solution is to use [tag:expect] (which uses [tag:tcl]) or similar tools. you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you prefer shell scripts.

Comment: Maybe you can use: `default_backend()$keyring_create("system", "mypasswd")`

Comment: @user2554330 Yes, you are right, you only need to do it once, but I wanted to create it this way as one of my tests in CI pipeline.. without human intervention..

Comment: `keyring_unlock()` needs to pass the keyring password programatically. Can we avoid sending the password everytime?